# How do I merge columns by two in a table in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table:

```
               1  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 ... 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75
0     rs535890807  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C ...  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C
1      rs74114776  G  G  G  G  G  G  G  G  G ...  G  G  G  G  G  G  G  G  G  G
2     rs572600766  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C ...  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C
```

I want to merge columns in it in this way:

```
0     rs535890807  CC  CC  CC
1      rs74114776  GG  GG  GG
2     rs572600766  CC  CC  CC
```

So merging columns by two, in other words. Is there an easy way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding the odd columns to the even:

```
df.iloc[:, ::2] + df.iloc[:, 1::2].values
```

Adding strings concatenates them. The `.values` is necessary because the slices of the DataFrame have different indices and so won't add as you might expect otherwise. How you implement this will also depend on what you want the resulting column names to be

Comment: thanks, it worked. After I dropped the first column from my table. btw does column indexing affect anything in this case? Since original table contains some 3-4 information columns.

Comment: The column names wont affect this method because ```.iloc``` selects based on integer position rather than by name, but you have consecutive integers for column names anyway. I'm not sure if this answers your question but if not, you'll have to be more specific. Do you mean you want to add columns in groups of 3 and 4? It is possible by changing the stepsize in ```iloc```, unless there is a mixture of 3s and 4s; that's a whole new problem. If you need more help, edit the question or ask a new one with an example

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question. I wanted to know if column names affect anything. I meant that original table had several columns which I did not need for the time being. So when I dropped them it affected the column names. So instead of 0,1,2,3,4,5... it became 1,4,6...

Answer (score 1):

Just add those two columns you want to combine

```
df['new_column'] = df['A'] + df['B']
```

It is equivalent to concatenating those two columns. I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: he has around 75 columns.. This has to be done in a loop

Comment: thanks, ill try to figure out a way to iterate over my columns. 75 columns is a test dataset. Real data is ~770k columns actually. =)